# Replace Airbag Unit on Audi A3 8L?

Tags: audi, supplemental-restraint-system

My airbag unit isn't working and needs to be replaced. The car is Audi A3 8L ('97) 1.9 TDI, 110hp.

Using VCDS, I found that serial number of that part is: 1J0 909 603

And now, in аutomorgue, I found a part **with the same serial number**, but it says that part is from Audi A3 8L ('97) 1.9 TDI, **but 90hp.**

So, my question is, can I use that part for replacement?

Comment: I think your going into very risky territory replacing any safety component with something that is possibly not exactly the same as the part you are removing.

Comment: The store you're looking at probably didn't put the right hp rating for the engine. If it has the same serial number and is coming from the same year/make/model/engine you're needed, I'll bet it's the same exact one. I do agree with DucatiKiller, though ... I think purchasing airbags used, in and of itself, is a risky proposition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I would not ever mess with airbags. This is not a project for a weekend driveway mechanic. Accidental activation can be fatal if you happen to be the wrong place at the wrong time with the wrong body part (i.e skull for example). Factory trained qualified mechanics know how to do it safely. Using parts designed exclusively for safety from vehicles that have accidents  is never a good idea. A tail light assembly or a bumper is one thing- Airbags absolutely not. It is not worth the risk. If you do not know the history of the part or if is compatible with your vehicle-Don't do it.

As someone who was almost killed by an well functioning airbag deploying during a accident - a head on collision with a drunk driver at 110 km/h. I can tell it hurts like hell for months afterwards. To save a few hundred dollars is not worth it. Not for you or your family.